# SwipeRefreshLayout not visible after the scroll down of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

My layout file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayoutColleague"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.ms.engage.utils.recycler.EmptyRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/colleagues_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

code

```
swipeRefreshLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayoutColleague);
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.pull_to_refresh);
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

Comment: Please refrain from repeatedly rolling back your question to earlier stages. Make sure your question is the best you can make it, and only update it if you have more details that can help you get an answer.

Comment: It's OK, we all make mistakes. Take care next time. Good luck! :)